DNA sequence ambiguous
I'm new to the Fourier transform and am exploring its application to DNA sequences. I plan to use the Voss representation, where each nucleotide is represented with binary values. However, DNA sequences often contain ambiguous bases (e.g., "R" can represent "G" or "A"), which isn't addressed in the papers I've read.
Here’s how one-hot encoding can represent these ambiguities:
nucleotide_dict = {
    "A": [1, 0, 0, 0],
    "G": [0, 1, 0, 0],
    "C": [0, 0, 1, 0],
    "T": [0, 0, 0, 1],
    "U": [0, 0, 0, 1],
    "Y": [0, 0, 1, 1],
    "R": [1, 1, 0, 0],
    "W": [1, 0, 0, 1],
    "S": [0, 1, 1, 0],
    "K": [0, 1, 0, 1],
    "M": [1, 0, 1, 0],
    "D": [1, 1, 0, 1],
    "V": [1, 1, 1, 0],
    "H": [1, 0, 1, 1],
    "B": [0, 1, 1, 1],
    "X": [1, 1, 1, 1],
    "N": [1, 1, 1, 1],
    "-": [0, 0, 0, 0],
}

Given the linear nature of the Discrete Fourier Transform, Voss representation traditionally uses binary encoding:
"A": [1, 0, 0, 0],
"G": [0, 1, 0, 0],
"C": [0, 0, 1, 0],
"T": [0, 0, 0, 1]

My question is: Will using one-hot encoding for ambiguous bases significantly impact the DFT result?
Thanks in advance.

I thought Uracil (U) was only found in RNA and not DNA.

@AndyWalls that's correct (AFAIK). But it is handy to keep U in such a dictionary in case someone throws an RNA sequence at it for whatever reason.

I think it would be better to use probabilities as in:
nucleotide_dict = {
    "A": [1, 0, 0, 0],
    "G": [0, 1, 0, 0],
    "C": [0, 0, 1, 0],
    "T": [0, 0, 0, 1],
    "U": [0, 0, 0, 1],
    "Y": [0, 0, 0.5, 0.5],
    "R": [0.5, 0.5, 0, 0],
    "W": [0.5, 0, 0, 0.5],
    "S": [0, 0.5, 0.5, 0],
    "K": [0, 0.5, 0, 0.5],
    "M": [0.5, 0, 0.5, 0],
    "D": [0.333, 0.333, 0, 0.333],
    "V": [0.333, 0.333, 0.333, 0],
    "H": [0.333, 0, 0.333, 0.333],
    "B": [0, 0.333, 0.333, 0.333],
    "X": [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
    "N": [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
    "-": [0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3],
}

Why this encoding? We can consider the DNA data as strictly one-hot (only one base has value 1, the rest have value 0) Voss encoded random variable $X$ that follows the above probabilities for 1s. With that encoding the probabilities are equal to expectations $\operatorname{E}[X]$. Because DFT is a linear transformation, the expectation of the DFT, $\operatorname{E}[\operatorname{DFT}(X)]$, has the nice property that:
$$\operatorname{E}[\operatorname{DFT}(X)] = \operatorname{DFT}(\operatorname{E}[X]),$$
meaning that you get $\operatorname{E}[\operatorname{DFT}(X)]$ by calculating the DFT of the probabilities. So probabilities seem quite a natural encoding for uncertain data in this application.
I've used roughly the natural genomic base frequencies for -. I don't really know what you should have for X, N, and -. It depends on whether natural frequencies were already taken into account during sequencing as prior probabilities, a consideration which applies also to the other uncertain bases with 2 or 3 alternatives, and on how you want to handle alignment gaps if you have those in the data.
